# Using databag in CHEF recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, recipe, databags

I have been struggling for over a week to solve this issue. Is there anyone who can help me out solving this.

I have a databag mongo, the contents of the databag is:

```
{ "firstuser": {
"id": "firstuser",
"password": "123",
"db": "mydb",
"role": "readWrite"
},
"seconduser": {
"id": "seconduser",
"password": "123",
"db": "mydb",
"role": "readWrite"
},
"thirduser": {
"id": "thirduser",
"password": "123",
"db": "mydb",
"role": "read"
},
"id": "users"
}
```

I want to loop through the databag, in order to create users in MongoDB. This is what I have come up with (and a lot more fruitless attempts)

```
users_databag_item = data_bag_item('mongodb', 'users')
users_databag_item.each_pair do | user, values |
log "db.createUser( { user: '#{values['id']}', pwd: '#{values['password']}', roles: [ { role: '#{values['role']}', db: '#{values['db']}' } ] } )"
end
```

The output of the script above is;

1. log[printing the records: db.createUser( { user: 'firstuser', pwd: '123', roles: [ { role: 'read', db: 'mydb' } ] } ) ] action write
2. log[printing the records: db.createUser( { user: 'seconduser', pwd: '123', roles: [ { role: 'read', db: 'mydb' } ] } ) ] action write
3. log[printing the records: db.createUser( { user: 'thirduser', pwd: '123', roles: [ { role: 'read', db: 'mydb' } ] } ) ] action write
4. log[printing the records: db.createUser( { user: '', pwd: '', roles: [ { role: '', db: '' } ] } ) ] action write

Have a look at row 4, it contains an empty record. It seems that the loop also uses ("id": "users"). Is there a way to filter out this entry?

To prove this I have added "id": "users", "password": "123" which resulted in 2 extra empty records.

So, I need to filter out: ("id": "users"). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can put filter for the object type of the values:-

```
users_databag_item = data_bag_item('mongodb', 'users')
users_databag_item.values.each do | values |
    log "db.createUser( { user: '#{values['id']}', pwd: '#{values['password']}', roles: [ { role: '#{values['role']}', db: '#{values['db']}' } ] } )" if !values.is_a? (String)
end
```

or

```
users_databag_item = data_bag_item('mongodb', 'users')
users_databag_item.each_pair do | id, values |
    log "db.createUser( { user: '#{values['id']}', pwd: '#{values['password']}', roles: [ { role: '#{values['role']}', db: '#{values['db']}' } ] } )" if !id.eql? "id"
end
```

Comment: Cheers mate! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Rajan - Did that helped?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it did work. In the end I have managed to fix it in another way.